# How can I extract correctly weights from my CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, output, conv-neural-network

First of all I trained my CNN-architecture:

```
adam =  optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(20, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape =(5,5,1), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Conv2D(30, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2)) # because the ROI is already small, we don't need subsampling
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.summary()
#plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
# compile the model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer= adam, metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=200, callbacks=[model_checkpoint], batch_size=1, verbose=1, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.5)
```

In the meanwhile I saved all weights epoch per epoch thanks to:

```
model_checkpoint=ModelCheckpoint('model_test{epoch:02d}.h5',save_freq=1,save_weights_only=True)
```

Then I extracted my weights, for example for the first epoch "model_test01.h5"

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
def isGroup(obj):
    if isinstance(obj,h5py.Group):
        return True
    return False

def isDataset(obj):
    if isinstance(obj,h5py.Dataset):
        return True
    return False

def getDatasetFromGroup(datasets,obj):
    if isGroup(obj):
        for key in obj:
            x = obj[key]
            getDatasetFromGroup(datasets,x)
    else:
        datasets.append(obj)

def getWeightsForLayer(layerName, filename):
   weights = []
   with h5py.File(filename, mode='r') as f:
       for key in f:
           if layerName in key:
              obj = f[key]
              datasets = []
              getDatasetFromGroup(datasets,obj)

              for dataset in datasets:
                  w = np.array(dataset)
                  weights.append(w)
   return weights
           #print(key, f[key])
           #o = f[key]
           #for key1 in o:
               #print(key1,o[key1])
               #r = o[key1]
               #for key2 in r:
                   #print(key2,r[key2])
weights = getWeightsForLayer("conv2d_6","./model_test01.h5")
#for w in weights:
    #print(w.shape)
print(weights)
```

But I fail to understand output, because a list "weights" with two float32-elements (basically two numpy array) the first one with 20 elements (guess 20 is the number of filter in the first convolution layer) and the second one with (3,3,1,20) dimension (so impossibile to open). How can I understand this output?

Answer (score 1):

The two "float32-elements" you have are corresponding to the weights of filter and biases of the conv layer. 
The **weights of filter** will have shape (3, 3, 1, 20) and **biases** will have shape (20), because you have 20 filters, and one bias value for each fiter.

(3, 3, 1, 20) is represented in the form **(width_of_filter, height_of_filter, depth_of_filter, number_of_filters)**